# Bundling images of dependencies into main module's bundle

Tags: webpack

I am facing this issue for which I have spent good two days on. Please help. I would greatly appreciate any leads, solutions or clarifications if this is not how webpack works or how to get it supported.

I have 2 projects:
 1. `consumer` 
 2. `dependency`

Both are basic es6 modules bundled using webpack.

`dependency` module is a **reusable module** intended to be reused by other modules.
`consumer` module uses `dependency` module as a npm dependency.

`dependency` module ships a component **with its own image asset** (it's (es6) exported from the js as well). The bundling output correctly generates the image asset along with generated js in the 'dist' output directory directly with correct import address in the generated js. All good here.

`consumer` module uses the `dependency`. The `consumer`'s generated bundle identifies the `dependency` bundle correctly and includes it.

However, **the problem is**, the image that was exported/bundled by `dependency` module is **not** readily included by `consumer`'s bundle and not included/copied to the relevant folder specified for image assets (in file-loader config) while executing the webpack on config of `consumer`'s .

---

**dependency**/src/index.js

```
import anyImage from './img/any.jpg'; // image any.jpg available at this path

const foo = function() {
    return "hello!";
};

export {foo, anyImage};
```

---

**dependency**/webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/index.js',

    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'index.js',
        libraryTarget: 'umd'
    },

    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: "file-loader",
                        options: {
                            name: "[name].[ext]"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.js?$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader'
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

---

**consumer**/src/index.js

```
import {foo, anyImage} from "dependency";
import placeholderImage from './img/placeholder_350x150.png';

document.getElementById('placeholderImage').src = placeholderImage;

setTimeout(() => {
    document.getElementById('placeholderImage').src = anyImage;
}, 2000);
```

---

**consumer**/webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/index.js',

    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'my-widget.js',
        libraryTarget: 'umd'
    },

    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: "file-loader",
                        options: {
                            name: "[name].[ext]",
                            publicPath: "/dist/"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.js?$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader'
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

---

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

i think you can make a console log for the anyImage in 'consumer/src/index.js' and 'dependency/src/index.js', i guess you will get the answer.

The imported 'anyImg' in the consumer project is just a string -- '/static/img/xxx.png' instead of an accessed image path.